# How can I prove or disprove that the following functions are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \mapsto (-x, |y|)$

$g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto (y-x,0,x-y)$

$h: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z) \mapsto  \sqrt[3]{(x^3+y^3+z^3)}$

$t: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4, (x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x,x-y,x^2-y^2)$

Can someone tell me please how to prove that a function is linear or disaprove it. I have found on the internet that a function is linear if these conditions are held:

If $f:\mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ is a map between vector $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (over any field $\mathbb{F}$), then f is linear if and onl if:

1) $f(v_1+v_2)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)$

2) $f(av)=af(v)$

for all $v,v_1,v_2\in \mathbb{V}$ and all $a\in \mathbb{R}$

If someone can explain maybe why this is true and how to use it.

And yes, I have been loking on internet but can't finds anything.

Comment: Why is this true? It is the definition of a linear mapping, one can't ask wether it's true or false. And regarding your question: you just have to check if the given functions have the two properties you listed, e.g. for the first one, if $$f(v_1+v_2)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)$$ all you have to do is pluck in $v_1=(x_1,y_1),v_2=(x_2,y_2)$ and check if the equation holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *disprove* linearity, you'll need some kind of example.

Take the first function.  This one is *not* linear.  To show that this is the case, we need an example such as
$$
v_1 = (0,1), \quad v_2 = (0,-1)
$$
We find that 
$$
f(v_1 + v_2) = f[(0,0)] = (0,0)
$$
On the other hand,
$$
f(v_1) + f(v_2) = f[(0,1)] + f[(0,-1)] = (0,1) + (0,1) = (0,2)
$$
So, the first function is **not** linear.

*Proving* linearity, on the other hand, requires that we show linearity holds for *every* possible input.

Take the second function.  To show that this is linear, we need to show that both parts of the definition hold.  To prove the first property, we consider any pair of inputs $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.  We then have
$$
f[(x_1,y_1,z_1) + (x_2,y_2,z_2)] = 
f[(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)] = \\
= \cdots = 
f(x_1,y_1,z_1) + f(x_2,y_2,z_2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Simply apply the definition to the given functions.

1) $f(v_1+v_2)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)$

2) $f(av)=af(v)$

becomes, for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \mapsto (-x, |y|)$:

1) $f((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))=f((x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2))\\=(-(x_1+x_2),|y_1+y_2|)\\=f((x_1,y_1))+f(x_2,y_2)\\=(-x_1,|y1|)+(-x_2,|y_2|)\\=(-(x_1+x_2),|y_1|+|y_2|)$

2) $f(a(x,y))=f((ax,ay))=(-ax,|ay|)=af(x)=a(-x,|y|)=(-ax,a|y|)$.

What do you think about these assertions ?